# iPhone - Retrieve NASA picture of the day

Tags: iphone, image

I would like to use NASA picture of the day in my application.

I have searched a lot how to retrieve it, but so far I found no answer.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do it?

Thanks,
Andrei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Find the URL for the NASA picture of the day's image file.
2) run this code:

```
NSString *NasaUrlStr = @"http:/nasa/imageoftheday.jpg";  // fill in correct path here
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:NasaUrlStr];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
self.myImageView.image = img;
```

If you want to get "fancy" you could run the "[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]" in a background thread so you don't stall your user interface while the image is downloading.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that I can not find that specific URL. The NASA picture of the day URL is changing from picture to picture.